# Error while running OpenCV based C# code 

Tags: c#, opencv

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

This is the error I got, on this line:

```
videoCapture = highgui.CvCreateCameraCapture(0);
```

The project shows no warnings or compilation errors so what can be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this almost certainly means is that your application is being compiled as 64-bit, whereas the code in OpenCV is 32-bit, or vice-versa.

In Visual Sudio:

1. Right click on your project in Solution Explorer and choose "Properties"
2. Choose the "Build" tab in the project properties that open
3. Look at the "Platform Target" option about a quarter of the way down
4. Set it to `x86` if it's currently set to `x64` or `Any CPU`

Now try re-running your application, the error should no longer occur.

*Note:* The [download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.2/) for OpenCV states that "**It does not contain 64-bit binaries**"